# How to make comic-like edges and lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop

can someone tell me how to get the corners and lines from one image changed so that they look as comic like as in picture 2?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve wavy edges in a set of geometrical blocks we can apply distortion filters.

Below examples were done with Gimp but the basic approach will be similar with other applications (names of filters may vary however).

1. *Distorts:* Whirl and pitch filter:

   [image]
2. [G'Mic Gimp plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/13469) *Deformations - Water*:

   [image]
3. *G'Mic Deformations Water* plus *G'Mic Repair - Recursive Median* for rounded corners:

   [image]

Default settings of deformation tools may overdo the effect. We therefore have to start with very low deformation settings.

The aliasing effect seen on the light area on the bottom may not have been wanted. In case you need it then this will be just be another deformation tool to add.